# How to manually call observer.onNext in rxJava

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java, rx-android

I am relatively new to RxJava/RxAndroid. I have been using AsyncTask to do my long running tasks before now.
I have converted most of my AsyncTask to RxJava but this one.
The particular problem I am having is calling something like AsyncTask's `publishProgress(params);` in
the background thread. I need to do this to update the progress of a `ProgressBar`.

**First this is the code in AsyncTask**

```
private static class AddBooksToDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    //dependencies removed

    AddBooksToDatabase(AddBooksDbParams params) {
        //Removed assignment codes
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        //Initializing custom SQLiteOpenHelper and SQLite database
        File mFile = new File(mFolderPath);

        int booksSize = getFilesInFolder(mFile).size();
        String[] sizeList = {String.valueOf(booksSize)};
        //The first publishProgress is used to set the max of the progressbar
        publishProgress(sizeList);

        for (int i = 0; i < booksSize; i++) {
            //publishProgress with current item, current file
            publishProgress(String.valueOf(i), getFilesInFolder(mFile).get(i).getName());
            //Inserting current items in database. Code removed
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Show ProgressBar
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        //Hide ProgressBar
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        if (values.length == 1) {
            //The first call to publishProgress
            mProgressBar.setMax(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
        } else {
            //Subsequent calls to publish progress
            Log.i(TAG, "Current item is " + values[0] + " and current file is " + values[1]);
            infoText.setText(values[1]);
            mProgressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]), true);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        cancel(true);
    }
}
```

**Code Using RxJava**

```
final Observable<String[]> addBooksObserver = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String[]>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String[]> subscriber) {
            subscriber.onNext(setAddSubscription());
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }
    })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

private String[] setAddSubscription() {
    S//Initializing custom SQLiteOpenHelper and SQLite database
    File mFile = new File(mFolderPath);

    int booksSize = getFilesInFolder(mFile).size();
    String[] sizeList = {String.valueOf(booksSize)};
    //The first publishProgress is used to set the max of the progressbar
    addBooksObserver.doOnNext(addReturnParams(String.valueOf(sizeList.length), null, null));

    for (int i = 0; i < booksSize; i++) {
        EpubReader reader = new EpubReader();
        //publishProgress with current item, current file*
        addBooksObserver.doOnNext(addReturnParams(String.valueOf(sizeList.length),
                String.valueOf(i), getFilesInFolder(mFile).get(i).getName()));
        //Inserting current item in database. Code removed
    }
    return null;
}

private String[] addReturnParams(String totalItems, String currentItem, String currentFile) {
    return new String[]{totalItems, currentItem, currentFile};
}
```

The problem is that lines `addBooksObserver.doOnNext(addReturnParams(` are displaying this error
    *doOnNext (rx.functions.Action1) cannot be applied to (java.lang.String[])*

I don't know have any idea how to fix this because I thought that since  `setAddSubscription()` and `addReturnParams(String totalItems, String currentItem, String currentFile)` are returning String array then this shouldn't be a problem. Please can you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to pass the values to the `onNext` method of your `subscriber`, **not** the `doOnNext` method of your observable!

you also have to subscribe to the service. try something like this for your obserable:

```
Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String[]>() {
  @Override
  public void call(Subscriber<? super String[]> subscriber) {
    setAddSubscription(subscriber);
    subscriber.onCompleted();
  }
})
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(new Subscriber<String[]>() {
  @Override
  public void onCompleted() {
   // handle 'oparation is done'
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(Throwable e) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onNext(String[] values) {
    if (values.length == 1) {
        //The first call to publishProgress
        mProgressBar.setMax(Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
    } else {
        //Subsequent calls to publish progress
        Log.i(TAG, "Current item is " + values[0] + " and current file is " + values[1]);
        infoText.setText(values[1]);
        mProgressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(values[0]), true);

    }
  }
});
```

you also need to modify your private methods a little bit:

```
private void setAddSubscription(Subscriber<? super String[]> subscriber) {
  //Initializing custom SQLiteOpenHelper and SQLite database
  File mFile = new File(mFolderPath);

  int booksSize = getFilesInFolder(mFile).size();
  String[] sizeList = {String.valueOf(booksSize)};
  //The first publishProgress is used to set the max of the progressbar
  subscriber.onNext(addReturnParams(String.valueOf(sizeList.length), null, null));

  for (int i = 0; i < booksSize; i++) {
    EpubReader reader = new EpubReader();
    //publishProgress with current item, current file*
    subscriber.onNext(addReturnParams(String.valueOf(sizeList.length),
            String.valueOf(i), getFilesInFolder(mFile).get(i).getName()));
    //Inserting current item in database. Code removed
  }

}

private String[] addReturnParams(String totalItems, String currentItem, String currentFile) {
  return new String[]{totalItems, currentItem, currentFile};
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem is how to pass the value.

Comment: added some modifications of your methods

Comment: Thanks. It's fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Subject` to call onNext() manually like this:

```
 Subject<Event> event = Subject.create();
```

Now call the onNext() for sending event like:

```
 event.onNext("event");
```

Finally you can return `Observable` by using this code:

```
event.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
                .toObservable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Observer` should be like `Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>()` & in your `call` method you should loop through the `StringArray` & pass it to `onNext` for example:

```
@Override
public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
   for(String val : setAddSubscription()) {
       subscriber.onNext(val);
   }
   subscriber.onCompleted();
}
```

now `onNext` shall return you individual items & `onCompleted` will be called upon the loop is finished.

---

**Edit**

```
myObserver.subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
  @Override
  public void onCompleted() {
   // handle completion. 
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(Throwable e) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onNext(String value) {
    // do whatever with each value passed to onNext
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but please I don't know where to write it.

Comment: It is saying I cannot supply `val` as a parameter to `subscriber.onNext(val);`

Comment: @Ozuf 0ops, its because i supplied string[] instead of String only, please change check my edited answer in `public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber)`

Comment: because in your case you need to pass a `String[]` not a `String` to `subscriber.onNext()`

Comment: @Rithe true that, i was in a rush when i answered the question, however i have updated my answer before you even comment :)

Comment: even though she wants to return a `String[]` including multiple values from `addReturnParams()`

Comment: @Rithe, she/he needs to have a progress update which basically what is happening in onBackground             publishProgress(String.valueOf(i), getFilesInFolder(mFile).get(i).getName());
if you check the question correctly. logically how would you update a progress base on an array? while it should be updated based on single value.

Comment: @k0sh The same problem. See this line `subscriber.onNext(val);`

Comment: @Ozuf because you still having `Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String[]>() ` while it should be emitting String.
`Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>()`

Comment: @k0sh sure, usually you just need on value, but as you can see in the `onProgressUpdate` the application should able to handle one or more response values

Comment: `onProgressUpdate ` accept vargas but that does not mean that you should pass an array while logically in any progress update, the progress will be updated based on 1,2,3,4,5,6,7etc individually and not base on an array. the OP needs to think about their logic implementation.

Answer (score -1):

```
Observable.create(emitter -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                int[] ii = {i, i * 2};
                emitter.onNext(ii);
            }
            emitter.onComplete();
        }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(o -> {
            // update progress
            int[] i = (int[]) o;
            Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "oftad " + i[0] + " - " + i[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }, t -> {
            // on error
            Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }, () -> {
            // progress tamom shod
            Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
```